# Existing transaction detected in JobRepository - Spring Batch with Grails Plugin

Tags: grails, spring-batch

Every time I start my batch job it throws an IllegalStateException and says it detected a transaction in JobRepository. I did some research and removed all `@Transactional` annotations in my code.

I use the Grails Spring Batch Plugin you can find [here](https://github.com/johnrengelman/grails-spring-batch), and I work with Grails 2.3.11 and Java 8. My code looks like this:

### SimpleJobBatchConfig.groovy

```
beans {

    xmlns batch:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"

    batch.job(id: 'simpleJob') {
        batch.step(id: 'printStep') {
            batch.tasklet(ref: 'printHelloWorld')
        }
    }

    printHelloWorld(SimpleJobTasklet) { bean ->
        bean.autowire = 'byName'
    }

}
```

### BatchTestController.groovy

```
class BatchelorController {

    def batchTestService

    def index() {

    }

    def launchSimpleJob() {
        batchTestService.launchSimpleJob()
    } 
}
```

### BatchTestService.groovy

```
class BatchTestService {

    def springBatchService

    def launchSimpleJob() {
        springBatchService.launch("simpleJob")
    }

}
```

### SimpleJobTasklet.groovy

```
class SimpleJobTasklet implements Tasklet {

    @Override
    RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        println("Hello World!")
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails services are transactional by default. You can customize the settings for the whole class or per-method with `@Transactional` but if you have no annotations it's the same as having a class-scope Spring `@Transactional` annotation.

To make your service non-transactional, add `static transactional = false`, e.g.

```
class BatchTestService {

    static transactional = false

    def springBatchService

    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still quiet new to Grails, it's good to know that every service is `@transactional` by default.